# While loop decrements in JavaScript until it reaches 0 and prints "Blastoff"

Tags: javascript, while-loop, countdown, console.log, decrement

**Exercise:**

Declare a variable named countdown and assign it the value of 10. In a *while* loop, decrement the value of countdown once for every iteration and print it. Once countdown hits 0, print 'Blastoff' to the console.

**What I've done so far:**

```
var countdown = 10;{
    while (countdown > 0 || 0=== "Blastoff!"){
        console.log(countdown);
        countdown = countdown - 1;
    }
    console.log("Blastoff!");
}
```

This is the result until now that i thought it should be correct:

```
Output
>>>>Code is incorrect
The first line in your while's block should decrement the value of the variable countdown
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
Blastoff!
```

Comment: Isn't the feedback quite clear? You need to decrement first before printing.

Comment: `0=== "Blastoff!"` will **always** be false

Comment: or change `var countdown = 10;` to `var countdown = 9;`

Comment: I've already tried that and it doesn't work either. Can you please specify where and how should i place it?

Comment: @Cid If the OP declares and initializes `countdown` at `9`, then the first number shown should be `8`, so your advice doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: The message `The first line in your while's block should decrement the value of the variable countdown` is pretty clear. Just swap the first two lines in your loop.

Comment: @ScottMarcus not if nothing else is changed in the code

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there but have a few small mistakes to fix. First, remove this open bracket after `var countdown = 10;{` (I get it that it might be added by mistake when writing the question here).

Second, remove this part `|| 0=== "Blastoff!"` from the while conditions. This will always be false.

Third, and probably most important, move the decrement part `countdown = countdown - 1;` before the console.log.

Here's an example how your code will look after the changes:

```js
var countdown = 10;
while (countdown > 0){
    countdown--;
    console.log(countdown);
}
console.log("Blastoff!");
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? What did you change? What was wrong with the original code? What was the crucial mistake in the original code? What kind of error? A logical mistake? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65205615/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

It is finally correct:

```js
var countdown = 10;
while (countdown > 0){
    countdown--;
    console.log(countdown);
}
console.log("Blastoff");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
var countdown = 10

// Changed condition to greater than 1
while (countdown > 1){

    // Printing decremented countdown
    console.log(--countdown)
}

console.log("Blastoff!");
```